# Wordpress, Woocommerce: Is it possible to get the time when a customer added a product in the cart?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am wandering through the core files for sometimes and also tried searching in web but couldn't find any relevant hit. For some reason I need to get the time when a customer added a product in the cart. Can anyone suggest where should I look? Or any idea how can I implement this if I must. I am using Wordpress v4.1.3 along with woocommerce v2.3.5

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). BTW, it's "Thanks in advance", not "Thanks in advanced".